# Continuous rotation in AN with certain control behavior? (Speed)

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

My Goal is a continuous rotation of an object in Animation Nodes around on the z-axis that can be controlled via a value in the way that 0 means no rotation and 1 means certain speed. -1 would be reverse.

**Increment values, reassign values?**
My understanding of AN got tested in this case really hard. First of all the Rotation Input by default doesn’t use the Object Transform Output as a new Input, is there a way?
Second of all is there a way to “store” values or “reassign” them to get this certain kind of behavior.

My First idea was to simply do it with a time_info but multiplying the time_info, logically prouces reverse motion on curve descend. **Demo File** is 2.81

**Comparison to Unity C#**
Coding this behavior in unity and c# is easy, because of its incremental fashion: Every tick I can use the current rotation as new input and decide whether I want to add or subtract a certain amount. In AN the linear Time_Info Curve gets multiplied and clinched as a whole.

help would strongly be appreciated! :)

[image]

Comment: You want a rotation and your input is a speed curve? Correct?

Comment: @Leander yes, this is the case. Maby its simple, but i cant get my head around it.

Comment: as seconed option to this idea of reassigning values, i now thought about differential equations, because it seems a speed curve would be in this way connected to the rotation-value curve. math it not my stongsuit, so maby im wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>To be able to properly animate in Blender, it is important that frames can be evaluated indepedently without the need for a previous frame or *start frame*. (Sometimes you want to change the start frame, but frame X should still show the same content.)</sup>

Create an empty object, which controls the speed. I added and empty circle and keyframed its X-axis. Grab that Fcurve with Animation nodes.

The position on a frame is merely the accumulation of the speed-value on all previous frames.

To simplify the matter

- I use a starting position of `0`
- interpret the input speed value [from the fcurve] as *speed per frame*
- ignore the subframes (no differential equations) and pretend the speed to be constant for the duration of a frame

but you can easily add the first and second bullet points.

This means we have to get a list of speed values up to the current frame. For that, I use a loop with as many iterations as the current frame number and evaluate the speed-fcurve's value. The resulting list must be summed to get the actual value. I use it to control the X position of a cuboid.

With movement on multiple axis this actually the same.

[image: speed fcurve]

[image]

<sup>Final note, do not go the math routes. Although I don't know your context, integrals are most likely overkill.</sup>

Comment: thank you very much, really a great answer! Very much appreciated :)

Comment: to sum up the list i used the "reassign loop parameter", in case someone has a similar problem.